# How to retrieve values from SQLite 3 database on the basis of multiple check boxes selected at once in PHP?

Tags: php, html, checkbox, sqlite

I am new to PHP coding. I have different preferences for the user to select from my html page. I want to retrieve all the check boxes selected by the user and display the hotel names which have all those preferences in them. For example if a user selects "Roof top", "Sea side" and "Swimming pool" check boxes, then the hotels against which their is a 1 placed in the respective columns in the mytrip.db database must be retrieved all at once and get displayed. My code takes only one checkbox value and displays the hotel name against that only. I want to display the hotels that contain all the preferences.
My code is below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/php_checkbox.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<h2>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</h2>
                        <select id="mySelect" name="list">
                        <option selected>Select a place</option>
                        <option value="1">Lahore</option>
                        <option value="2">Dubai</option>
                        <option value="3">New York</option>
                        <option value="4">Canberra</option>
                        <option value="5">London</option>
                        </select>
<form action="php_checkbox.php" method="post">
<label class="heading">Select Your Preferences:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Swimming pool"><label>Swimming pool</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Roof top"><label>Roof top</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Sea side"><label>Sea side</label>



<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>

</html>
<?php include 'checkbox_value.php';?>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

checkbox_value.php code is below:

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('mytrip.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {

   }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
// Counting number of checked checkboxes.
$checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
$prefarray=array();
$i=0;
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
$prefarray[$i]= $selected;

echo "<p>".$prefarray[$i] ."</p>";
echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
$i++;
}
echo "<p>".$i ."</p>";
$sql =<<<EOF

      SELECT hotel_name from Dubai WHERE $prefarray[i]==1 AND $prefarray[i-1]==1 ;
EOF;

   $ret = $db->query($sql);
   while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
      echo "<p> <br /></p>\n";
      echo "\n". $row['hotel_name'] . "\n";
   }





   $db->close();
echo "<br/><b>Note :</b> <span>Similarily, You Can Also Perform CRUD Operations using These Selected Values.</span>";
}
else{
echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
}
}
?>
```

The problem with this code is that it only displays one checkbox value if I use query

```
SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE $selected==1
```

I tried to save the check box values selected by making an array "prefarray". But when I execute the query that I have posted in my checkbox_value.php code it gives me error of "Undefined offset 3 in prefarray". I want the data base query to have only those checkbox values that have been selected by the user. For example if the user has selected 2 out of three checkboxes then my query should look like

```
SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE $checkbox==1 AND $checkbox2==1;
```

Any help to achieve two of these tasks will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed and refactored (couldn't stop myself) your code.

I have changed column names to proper ones. There was some redundant code  which did nothing so I got rid of it. The main thing you were looking for is concatenating each chosen column in foreach loop. I'm also checking selected values against hard coded `$hotelOptions` for protection against sql injection.

Here is what I got:

**checkbox_value.php:**

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('mytrip.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {

}

$hotelOptions = array('swimming_pool', 'roof_top', 'sea_side');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['check_list']) && is_array($_POST['check_list'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
        $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
        echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        $where = '';
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
            echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
            if (array_search($selected, $hotelOptions) !== false) {
                $where .= " AND {$selected} = 1";
            }
        }
        $where = substr($where, 5, strlen($where));

        $sql = "SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE {$where};";

        $ret = $db->query($sql);
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
            echo "<p> <br /></p>\n";
            echo "\n". $row['hotel_name'] . "\n";
        }
        $db->close();
        echo "<br/><b>Note :</b> <span>Similarily, You Can Also Perform CRUD Operations using These Selected Values.</span>";
    } else {
        echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
    }
}
```

**html layout:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/php_checkbox.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <form action="checkbox_value.php" method="post">
            <h2>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</h2>
            <select id="mySelect" name="list">
                <option selected>Select a place</option>
                <option value="1">Lahore</option>
                <option value="2">Dubai</option>
                <option value="3">New York</option>
                <option value="4">Canberra</option>
                <option value="5">London</option>
            </select>
            <p class="heading">Select Your Preferences:</p>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="swimming_pool" id="checkbox_1">
            <label for="checkbox_1">Swimming pool</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="roof_top" id="checkbox_2">
            <label for="checkbox_2">Roof top</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="sea_side" id="checkbox_3">
            <label for="checkbox_3">Sea side</label>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
            </div>
            <?php include 'checkbox_value.php';?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After running your code i am getting "Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near &quot;;&quot;: syntax error in checkbox_value.php on line 35" . And also in fetchArray() function. Please guide how can I implement it?

Comment: try `$sql = "SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE ".$where.";";`

Comment: I have created database and this code is working properly on my machine. Can  you check what `$sql` contains? It should contain something like: `SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE swimming_pool = 1 AND roof_top = 1;`

Comment: after echoing the $sql i got "SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE ;" statement. I am using SQLite3 for database.

Comment: Note that I have changed column names to swimming_pool etc. Each possible value(your columns in db) in check_list has to be in `$hotelOptions`. If you did not change columns like I did in my script you have to change values of `$hotelOptions` to represent columns in your db.

Comment: Thanks alot for your great help! Can you please guide how can i handle the destination/place scenario in this case. As I have five destinations that people can choose from. The table should get selected accordingly in case of separate tables for each destination in a database.

Comment: I would ask you to create new question with updated script so we are on the same page and we can avoid confusion. It would also allow me to refactor code even further and not end up with bloated answers. I might end up answering in about 8h because right now I'm at work :).

Comment: Can you help me with this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384377/how-to-display-the-hotel-names-that-have-the-maximum-count-from-data-base-by-cal

Comment: I am done with implementing the destination part just i want to handle the counts task.

Comment: Totally, but I will be able to sit down to it at about 19:00 CEST.

Comment: Thanks a ton! :) It was a very big help from you.

Comment: Need your help again. Can you help me with this-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466907/how-to-verify-user-details-using-php-by-retrieving-data-from-sqlite3-database

Comment: No problem. Once again 19:00 CEST would be the earliest I can look into it.