# How to display the hotel names that have the maximum count from data base by calculating sum in PHP?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I am new to PHP coding. I want to display the names of the hotels from data base in ascending order according to the respective counts of the preferences selected by the user from the checkboxes. My code displays the names of the hotels according to the preferences entered by the user. The logic is to display the hotel name if there exists a "1" under the preference name in data base against that hotel. For example, if the user selects two checkboxes out of 7, "pool" and "gym" so, my code displays the hotels that have "1" in both the preferences of gym and pool in database. My data base looks like:

```
Hotel_id| Hotel_name| Pool| pool_count  | Gym | gym_count| spa | spa_count| 0                                               
1       Abc hotel     1      1.4         1       1.5       1      1.9
2       xyz hotel     1      1.2         0       0         0       0
3       xmk hotel     1      1.0         1       0.5       0       0
4       New hotel     1      1.99        0       0         0       0
5       old hotel     1      0.98        0       0         0       0
6       street hotel  1      0.78        0       0         0       0
.    .                .    .
.
.
```

I am using SQLite3 for making data base. If the user selects the check boxes of pool, gym and spa then all those hotels that have a "1" under the column of the pool, gym and spa must be retrieved (my code does this) then it should calculate the sum of the respective counts. For example it should add pool_count with gym_count and spa_count and then display the names of the hotels in ascending order according to their respective total sum values. I have tried to implement it by first making an array that contains all the column names of the counts and then a query that calculates the sum but I don't get how can I pass the specific column name of the preferences that have been selected by the user.

**php_checkbox.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/php_checkbox.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <form action="checkbox_value.php" method="post">
            <h2>PHP: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes</h2>
            <select id="mySelect" name="list">
                <option selected>Select a place</option>
                <option value="1">Lahore</option>
                <option value="2">Dubai</option>
                <option value="3">New York</option>
                <option value="4">Canberra</option>
                <option value="5">London</option>
            </select>
            <p class="heading">Select Your Preferences:</p>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="pool" id="checkbox_1">
            <label for="checkbox_1">Pool</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="gym" id="checkbox_2">
            <label for="checkbox_2">Gym</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="spa" id="checkbox_3">
            <label for="checkbox_3">Spa</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="is_beach" id="checkbox_4">
            <label for="checkbox_1">Beach</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="is_wifi" id="checkbox_5">
            <label for="checkbox_2">Wifi</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="is_familyoriented" id="checkbox_6">
            <label for="checkbox_3">Family oriented</label>

            <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="is_economical" id="checkbox_7">
            <label for="checkbox_3">Value for money</label>


            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
            </div>
            <?php include 'checkbox_value.php';?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**checkbox_value.php**:

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('mytrip.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {

}

$hotelOptions = array('pool', 'gym', 'spa', 'is_wifi', 'is_beach', 'is_familyoriented', 'is_economical');
$countOptions = array('pool_count', 'gym_count', 'spa_count', 'wifi_count', 'beach_count','family_count','econo_count');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['check_list']) && is_array($_POST['check_list'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
        $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
        echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        $where = '';
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
            echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
            if (array_search($selected, $hotelOptions) !== false) {
                $where .= " AND {$selected} = 1";
            }
        }
        $where = substr($where, 5, strlen($where));

      //  $sql = "SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE ".$where.";";
        $query= "SELECT SUM( ) FROM Dubai WHERE ".$where.";";
        $sql = "SELECT hotel_name FROM Dubai WHERE ".$where.";";
        echo "<p>".$where ."</p>";

        $ret = $db->query($sql);
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
            echo "<p> <br /></p>\n";
            echo "\n". $row['hotel_name'] . "\n";
        }
        $db->close();

    } else {
        echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
    }
```

The second task that I want to achieve is to display the data according to the destination selected by the user in the drop down list in "php_checkbox.php" code. I have given unique id's to each option in the list but don't get how can I dynamically send the city name in the query to open the table of that destination. My current query looks like:

```
SELECT hotel_name FROM London WHERE
```

How can I open the table for the city that has been selected from the drop down list by the user?

Help in this regard shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a table layout too? How is the pool, gym etc amenities are stored for the hotel? ... Never mind ... got it from the query.

Comment: Two Things ... 1. Do you really have separate table to store the hotels for each city? That's bad! 2. Can you just highlight the two things which are not working/you need help with.

Comment: @Hmmm: Yes, I have made separate tables for each destination in order to store data properly. The first thing I need to get fixed is to select the table of the city that has been selected by the user from the drop down list. For example if the user selected "London" in the drop down list then the table name in the query must get selected accordingly dynamically.

Comment: @Hmmm: The second task that I want to achieve is to display the hotels by calculating the sum of the counts of preferences selected by the user. My code displays hotels that contain the preferences but not by calculating the sum of respective counts of preferences. For example, a user selects pool, gym and spa from the check box, then the pool_count, gym_count and spa_count should be added together to calculate the total count and then the hotels must get displayed in ascending order according to their total counts.

Comment: @Hmmm: In the second task, the hotel that contains the preferences selected by the user and having the max count should get displayed first. Then the hotel that has the second highest count and contains all the preferences selected by the user should get displayed second.

Comment: @Hmmm: I have posted the table layout on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make ordering by selected fields almost the same as `$where` is done. I would map option names to their respective column counts: `'pool' => 'pool_count'`. Choosing from table selected by user is even more straightforward, just make array containing input values as indexes, table name as values and pick concatenate chosen index into query.

I have used simplified version of your code (only one city, less columns) but logic would work with your data as well just adjust it. There is one thing left, you should handle case where `$_POST['list']` does not contain proper value.

Here's code:

```
$hotelOptions = array('swimming_pool', 'roof_top', 'sea_side');
$countOptions = array(
    'swimming_pool' => 'swimming_pool_count',
    'roof_top' => 'roof_top_count',
    'sea_side' => 'sea_side_count',
);
$cities = array(1 => 'Dubai');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['check_list']) && is_array($_POST['check_list'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
        $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
        echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        $where = '';
        $order = '';
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
            echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
            if (array_search($selected, $hotelOptions) !== false) {
                $where .= " AND {$selected} = 1";
                $order .= " {$countOptions[$selected]} DESC,";
            }
        }
        $where = substr($where, 5, strlen($where));
        $order = substr($order, 0, strlen($order) - 1);

        if (isset($cities[$_POST['list']])) {
            $sql = "SELECT hotel_name FROM ".$cities[$_POST['list']]." WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY ".$order.";";

            $ret = $db->query($sql);

            while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
                echo "<p> <br /></p>\n";
                echo "\n". $row['hotel_name'] . "\n";
            }
            $db->close();
            echo "<br/><b>Note :</b> <span>Similarily, You Can Also Perform CRUD Operations using These Selected Values.</span>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! :) It was a really very big help from you.

Answer (score 0):

> it should add pool_count with gym_count and spa_count and then display
>   the names of the hotels in ascending order according to their
>   respective total sum values

For this you can do it in multiple way,

Get the submitted checkboxes, now when you have them just loop through them and make the string if it is checked:

```
$query_string = '';
foreach($selected_checkboxes as $name=>$value)
{
     if($value==1)
          $query_string .= "`$name` + ";
}
$query_string = rtrim($query_string, " + ");
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, ($query_string) AS AMENITIES_COUNT 
FROM xyz 
ORDER BY AMENITIES_COUNT DESC
```

PHP:

Just sum the amenities in the `usort` function and sort it based on that.

> dynamically send the city name in the query to open the table of that
>   destination

Making the query dynamic is pretty easy, you just need to understand what will change and what will not.

So when user selects a city and hits the submit button your query variable will become this:

```
$selected_city = $_POST['city'];
$query = "SELECT hotel_name FROM `$selected_city` WHERE ...";
```

You may need to use that city in your filter queries too. (will edit the answer in case I have missed something)

**===EDIT===**

Some Optimization in your code:

```
    $hotel_count_options = array ( ['pool'] => 'pool_count', ['gym'] => 'gym_count',  ['spa'] => 'spa_count', ['is_wifi'] => 'wifi_count', ['is_beach'] => 'beach_count', ['is_familyoriented'] => 'family_count', ['is_economical'] => 'econo_count' );
$where = '';
$query_select_string = '';
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
            echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
            if (array_search($selected, array_keys($hotel_count_options)) !== false) {
                $where .= " AND {$selected} = 1";
                $query_select_string .= "{$hotel_count_options['$selected']} + ";
            }
        }
$query_select_string = rtrim($query_string, " + ");
```

Now just change your select query string,

$sql = "SELECT hotel_name, $query_select_string as ame_count FROM Dubai WHERE ".$where." ORDER BY ame_count desc;";

Comment: The query that you have just posted for adding the counts is hard coded as its adding three specific counts all together. What I need is a query that dynamically adds the respective counts according to the preference selected by the user..

Comment: Well that is super easy too! ... Why don't you are for 2 min then I edit the answer ... You may need to make one array and then use implode?

Comment: for example, I have 7 preferences in total and the user may select any of the set of preferences each time. In the way you suggested I will have to make a number of combination of queries for catering every possible input given by the user

Comment: you may edit your answer to make the changes and implement implode as you are suggesting so that I may get what you are trying to tell

Comment: Updated the answer ... let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can you please place this piece of code in mine so that I get to know which part of code is to be removed from mine. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: because I have already created two arrays "hotelOptions" and "countOptions" and implemented a loop structure for getting multiple checkboxes at once, so not getting where to place your piece of code and what to remove in mine in order to make it work

Comment: Made some changes to "include" your code ... I think from here you should try to use the logic/concept to merge in your code. Happy Coding.

Comment: After running your edited piece of code I get a bundle of warnngs and an error. Nothing gets stored in "$query_string" and also in "$query_select_string". By echoing both of these variables I got to see that nothing gets stored in them both. Due to both these variables the query is not working. How to make these variables store the correct data?

Comment: EDIT: $query_select_string = rtrim($query_select_string, " + "); ... I think few edits like this you need to make!

Comment: Tried editing the way you suggested but that didn't help either :(

Comment: I think you should get the logic and try it on your own, also if stuck big time ... post code on fiddle or start chat and send screenshots.