# How to verify user details using PHP by retrieving data from SQLite3 database?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am new to PHP coding. I have created two forms. One is for signing up and the other for logging in. Unfortunately both fail to work due to some issues in the queries. I also searched and went through similar posts on this site but none solved my problem. I want to verify whether a user with the same id exists in the database "Users.db" at the time of signing up if any user enters the same id he should be notified to enter a valid id.

When I run my "sign in.php" code, it displays the following message on the screen without even waiting for the user to press the submit button/ sign up button.. "Number of rows found: 1 .This id is not available. Please enter a valid id." This message gets displayed even if the user enters a unique id that doesnt exist in the database before. Nothing gets stored in my database even if the id is unique by pressing the sign up button.

Secondly while logging in, the id and password entered by the user must be verified and matched with those stored in the database. He should be directed to the "index.html" page after successfully login in and only if he has signed up before. He should also be able to view his search history that is stored in "Search" table in the same database. This table contains two columns. One for the User id and the other for saving his search results.

The Search table looks like:

```
Id   | History
nl23   Grand Hayat Hotel
       Pearls Residencia Hotels
```

I am getting this error after running my code for login form "Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "AND": syntax error in D:\log in.php on line 54".

My log in form code is below:

**log in.php**

```
<body>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  



<h2>Log in page</h2>

<form method="post" action="">  
  Id: <input type="text" name="Id">
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="text" name="Password">
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" >  
</form>


<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('Users Data.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {

   }

   $id=null;
   $pass=null; 
   $id_exists=null; 
   if (isset($_POST['uid'])) {
    $id = $_POST['uid'];
}

   if (isset($_POST['passid'])) {
    $pass = $_POST['passid'];
    }

    $sql= " SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '" .$id. "' AND PASSWORD = '" .$pass. "';";
    $ret = $db->query($sql);
    $rows = count($sql);
    if ($rows > 0)
       {
         $id_exists = true;
         echo "You entered a valid id and password. ";
         $sql= "SELECT History FROM Search WHERE Id= " .$id. ";";
         $ret = $db->query($sql);
         //header("location:index.html");
       }
    else 
    {
      echo "Please enter a valid id and password. ";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My sign in form is below:

**sign in.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  



<h2>Sign in page</h2>

<form method="post" action="">  
  Id: <input type="text" name="Id">
  <br><br>
  Password: <input type="text" name="Password">
  <br><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" >  
</form>


<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('Users Data.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {

   }
   $id=null;
   $password=null;
   $email=null;
   $id_exists=false;
   $sql=null;
   $result=null;
   $rows=null;
   $ret=null;
   if (isset($_POST['Id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['Id'];
   }

   if (isset($_POST['Password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
   }

    if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {
      $email = $_POST['Email'];
    }


     $result= "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = " .$id. ";";
     // $ret = $db->query($result);
     //$ret = $db->exec($sql);
     echo "<p> The result query is ".$result ."</p>";
     $rows = count($result);
     echo "<p> Number of rows found: ".$rows ."</p>";

     if ($rows > 0)
       {
         $id_exists = true;
         echo "This id is not available. Please enter a valid id. ";
       }

       else 
     {
         $sql= "INSERT INTO Users (ID,PASSWORD, EMAIL)
          VALUES ('$id','$password','$email');" ;
         $ret = $db->query($sql);
         //$ret = $db->exec($sql);
        // header("location:index.html");
       }

 if(!$ret){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {

   }
$db->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me as i am stuck in both these codes.

Comment: i don't think that this is a valid sqlite3 database file name: - `Users Data.db`

Comment: I have my sqlite3 database with this name :)

Comment: I am able to add or modify values manually in this file "Users Data.db" which means that its all valid :)

Comment: well then, add your SQLite3 class.

Comment: I have extended "MyDB" class from SQLite3 in both my codes.

Comment: remove `$sql =<<< EOF`, and `EOF`. then share errors. you have errors on your syntax.

Comment: After removing the statements that you suggested my sign in.php cpde ran but the problem with it is that it displays the message "Number of rows found: 1

This id is not available. Please enter a valid id. " in both the cases. The same message is displayed even if the user enters a unique id that doesnt exist in the database before.

Comment: By running my log in.php code i am getting this error ""Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "AND": syntax error in D:\log in.php on line 54" and i dont have the EOF statements written in my log in.php code.

Comment: Nothing gets inserted in the database by running sign in.php code

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is checking if `$_POST` is set or is not empty. Only then you want to process user input. One more thing is that you should wrap `$pass` in quotes as it is a string and will be interpreted as column name if not surrounded with quotes.

Here's code:

**log in.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
        label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>



<h2>Log in page</h2>

<form method="post" action="">
    Id: <input type="text" name="Id">
    <br><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="Password">
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" >
</form>


<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('Users Data.db');
        }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }

    $id=null;
    $pass=null;
    $id_exists=null;
    if (isset($_POST['Id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['Id'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Password'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['Password'];
    }

    $sql= " SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = '" .$id. "' AND PASSWORD = '" .$pass. "';";
    $ret = $db->query($sql);
    $rows = count($sql);
    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        $id_exists = true;
        echo "You entered a valid id and password. ";
        $sql= "SELECT History FROM Search WHERE Id= " .$id. ";";
        $ret = $db->query($sql);
        //header("location:index.html");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please enter a valid id and password. ";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**sign in.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
        label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>



<h2>Sign in page</h2>

<form method="post" action="">
    Id: <input type="text" name="Id">
    <br><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="Password">
    <br><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" >
</form>


<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('Users Data.db');
        }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }
    $id=null;
    $password=null;
    $email=null;
    $id_exists=false;
    $sql=null;
    $result=null;
    $rows=null;
    $ret=null;
    if (isset($_POST['Id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['Id'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['Password'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
    }


    $result= "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = " .$id. ";";

    echo "<p> The result query is ".$result ."</p>";
    $rows = count($result);
    echo "<p> Number of rows found: ".$rows ."</p>";

    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        $id_exists = true;
        echo "This id is not available. Please enter a valid id. ";
    }

    else
    {
        $sql= "INSERT INTO Users (ID,PASSWORD, EMAIL)
          VALUES ('$id','$password','$email');" ;
        $ret = $db->query($sql);
        //$ret = $db->exec($sql);
        // header("location:index.html");
    }

    if(!$ret){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }
    $db->close();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would love to know what is this app that you are developing. Is it just learning project which will not see the light of production server? I'm asking because there are few fundamental parts that you did not get quite right and would like to guide you towards best practices in programming.

Comment: Its a website that i am working on. Currently working on the data base part.

Comment: My sign in.php still isnt adding data in the database :( And its also not notifying that the id already exists in case of entering an id that exists in the database before..

Comment: By running my log in.php code it displays "You have entered a valid id and password" even if I enter a different id that doesnt exist in db. Plus it shows this error on line 113 "SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near &quot;;&quot;: syntax error"

Comment: Please help me :( I am stuck bad in both these codes. Don't know where have I gone wrong. Tried to do it through many ways but didnt help..